# Generalizing a polynomial to have multiple root at $x=0$

Tags: polynomials

> Let $P(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $n$ such that $P(x)=Q(x)P^{\prime\prime}(x)$, where $Q(x)$ is a quadratic polynomial and $P^{\prime\prime}(x)$ is the second derivative of $P(x)$. Show that if $P(x)$ has at least two distinct roots then it must have $n$ distinct roots. (Roots can be real or complex).

---

There's a hint given in the book which tells:

> Without loss of generality assume $P(x)$ has a multiple root at $x=0$, compare the largest power of $x$ dividing both sides.

Can anyone please help to justify how can make such an assumption without losing generality? Like what if $P(x)$ doesn't have a multiple root at $x=0$?

Comment: You can shift $P$, that is if $-x_0$ is a double root then you consider polynomial $P(x+x_0)$.

Comment: One could always recenter any given double root.

Comment: @EkeneE. So they are assuming there's a multiple root and they are shifting that root to x=0?

Comment: Well, that isn't exactly what "without loss of generality" means. Just that you make an assumption (here it's that there's a multiple root at $x = 0$) so that we can always recover any other general case (for instance, if we had a multiple root at $x = a$ for $a \neq 0$, then we'd just use $x - a$ as our $x$ instead, which obviously satisfies $x - a = 0$) via that assumption.

Comment: @EkeneE. What if the root in question is a complex root?

Comment: Same thing for complex $a$.

Comment: Note that this problem is readily doable even without the hint your book provides.

Comment: @EkeneE. Can you give a hint about your solution? Even though the post isn't exactly about that

Comment: I have added a solution below. Feel free to accept if it's satisfactory.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose towards contradiction that $P(x)$ doesn't have $n$ distinct roots, so that it takes the form $P(x) = (x - a)^k A(x)$, where $k$ is at least $2$, $a \in \mathbb{C}$, and $A(a) \neq 0$ is some quotient polynomial. Then we have that
\begin{align*}
P''(x) &= \left(k(x-a)^{k-1}A(x) + (x - a)^kA'(x)\right)'\\
&= k(k-1)(x-a)^{k-2}A(x) + 2k(x-a)^{k-1}A'(x) + (x-a)^kA''(x)\\
&= (x-a)^{k-2}\left(k(k-1)A(x) + 2k(x -a)A'(x) + (x-a)^2A''(x)\right)\\
&= (x-a)^{k-2}B(x),
\end{align*}
for some polynomial $B$. Now as $B(a) = k(k-1)A(a) \neq 0$, $B(x)$ doesn't have any factors of $(x-a)$, so that for some constant $C_1$,
$$(x-a)^kA(a) = P(x) = Q(x)P''(x) = Q(x)(x-a)^{k-2}B(x) \implies Q(x) = C_1(x-a)^2,$$
and $A(x) = C_1B(x)$. Therefore
$$A(a) = C_1B(a) = C_1k(k-1)B(a) \implies C_1 = \frac{1}{k(k-1)},$$
which would mean that
$$P(x) = Q(x)P''(x) = \frac{1}{k(k-1)}\cdot (x-a)^2P''(x),$$
and this is the same as
$$P''(x) = k(k-1) \cdot \frac{P(x)}{(x-a)^2}.$$
But by expanding the $(x-a)$ powers of $P(x)$, this only happens if $P(x) = C_2(x-a)^k$ for some constant $C_2$; contradiction.